# Вызов cgi-скриптов без расширения

Tags: cgi, python, apache, веб-программирование

Братцы!

Вопрос по вебпрограммированию. Есть некий проект на питоне. cgi-скрипты имеют, соответственно, расширение `py`. Находятся на сервере в директории `www`. Исполнение там скриптов настроено и работает. Что можно сделать, чтобы вызывать их из строки браузера по именам *без расширения*?

**Пример**

`Имеется` адрес

```
http://aaaa.ru/page1.py
```

`Нужно`, чтобы вызывался строкой

```
http://aaaa.ru/page1
```

Comment: RewriteRule page1$ page1.py, не?

Comment: Спасибо, не работает

Comment: Что именно не работает? (RewriteLog) Питона под рукой нет, но [вот](http://klopp.net.ru/test/test1). И [вот](http://klopp.net.ru/test/test2).

Comment: обычно  это делается либо реврайтом на питоновские скрипты, либо на "роутер", либо запускается приложение вебсервера (без апача с nginx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОК, всем спасибо! Заработала такая редирекция:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^www/test$ test.py
```